# How do I grab the UTI or MIME Type from a video asset fetched using PHAsset.fetchAsset?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, phasset

I've run into an issue where I can't seem to figure out a good way of grabbing the UTI or MIME type from a video asset after fetching it from the photo library.

```
let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: someCollection, options: videosOnly)
(iterating over each asset in assets...)
PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil) { (AVAsset: avAsset, AVAudioMix: avAudioMix, info) in
    (I'm trying to find the UTI/MIME type here...)
}
```

One iffy solution I found was to grab the pathExtension of the file by casting the avAsset as a AVURLAsset:

```
guard let avURLAsset = avAsset as? AVURLAsset else { return }
let videoExt = avURLAsset.url.pathExtension
```

This seems to get the corresponding filetype ('m4v', 'mov', 'mp4') in basic test cases, but I'm worried that this is not a robust enough solution.  I saw another post ([Finding image type from NSData or UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147311/finding-image-type-from-nsdata-or-uiimage/5042365#5042365)) that details grabbing the image type by looking at the bytes of NSData, but did not touch on video files.

I have also tried the solution suggested at [How to get MIME type for image or video in iOS 8 using PHAsset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724615/how-to-get-mime-type-for-image-or-video-in-ios-8-using-phasset):

```
let requestContentEditingOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: requestContentEditingOptions) { (contentEditingInput, contentEditingInfo) in
    guard let videoUTI = contentEditingInput?.uniformTypeIdentifier else { completion(nil); return }
}
```

Unfortunately, the uniformTypeIdentifier property came up as nil when I attempted this.  If anyone sees a potential problem with my implementation of this, I'd love to hear it.

Has anyone else run into this before?  Would love to hear any ideas or if anyone things the pathExtension is a reasonable option for a production app.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724615/how-to-get-mime-type-for-image-or-video-in-ios-8-using-phasset?s=1|108.6600

Comment: Forgot to mention -- I actually tried that solution and, oddly, the uniformTypeIdentifier property was nil when I tried to access it.
(editing in sample code...)